# Translate cURL command line into PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to translate this cURL command into PHP cURL code:

> ```
> > curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json' --data
> > 'cursor=-1&screen_name=somename' --header 'Authorization: OAuth
> > oauth_consumer_key="key", oauth_nonce="nonce",
> > oauth_signature="signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
> > oauth_timestamp="timestamp", oauth_token="token", oauth_version="1.0"'
> > --verbose
> ```

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
> $ch = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="key", oauth_nonce="nonce", oauth_signature="signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="timestamp", oauth_token="token", oauth_version="1.0"'));
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=somename');
> $page = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
```

error i am getting

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

however it works in the standard curl command

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide curl with the certificate chain that will allow it to verify Twitter's SSL certificate as valid. To do this, download the requisite certificate signatures [from here](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/cacert.pem) and save them into a plain file (I 'll assume you name it `cacert.pem`).

Then, before making the request, set `CURLOPT_CAINFO` to point to this file:

```
// assumes file in same directory as script
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly enable SSL certificate verification instead of relying on default settings:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Comment: Now I get this error: _setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: cacert.pem CApath: none_ What can I do with that?

Comment: @loudislav: Hmm, maybe you need to set `CURLOPT_CAPATH` to `.` as well (assuming certificate file in current directory). Also make triple sure that the path for the cert file is correct.